# Laptop randomly shuts off when not on AC Power

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire

**Before anything else, my laptop:

Acer Aspire E14 (E5-475G-380U)

i3-7100U/GT940MX

4GB RAM

1 year old**

I just suddenly had this problem where my laptop shuts off suddenly when on Battery power. The battery is fully charged and i don't suspect that the battery is dead. When it randomly shuts off, and i open it again without the ac, it will turn on, i'll hear the fan, or maybe the HDD spin for about 3 seconds, then it will shut off again. It will repeat the same thing about two times (without me hitting the Power Button), before it boots up normally, but will again, shut off. Is there a problem with the battery? or this is something else?

Sidenotes: I slept about 12:30am-ish, and woke up at 6:30am. When i turned on the laptop, the issue of turning off and ond again is still there, but it repeated for 5 times now before it boots normally (in the 5th, it showed the "Acer" logo), and i plugged the charger in. same thing, 100% battery. but when windows booted up, the time is STILL, 12:30am, but in reality, its already 6:30am. Does this have something to do with the CMOS?